# How to prevent saving file in vim

Tags: vim

I'm customizing vim (vimdiff) as a testing tool for diffing certain files, and would like to disable saving the files completely - however, I haven't been able to stop `:w!` .. I've tried starting vim/vimdiff with `-R` option, and I have also tried setting `cpoptions` to contain `W`, which means:

> ```
>                                                             cpo-W
>             W       Don't overwrite a readonly file.  When omitted, ":w!"
>                     overwrites a readonly file, if possible.
> ```

..but vim seems not to care about this:

```
echo yo > foo

vim -R foo

:set cpoptions=aABceFsW

:set cpoptions?
cpoptions=aABceFsW

:w
E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)

:w!
"foo" 1L, 3C written
```

..bug, or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: My understanding: You just told Vim that it should run in "readonly mode". The file itself is not readonly.  If you `chmod -w foo`, then Vim would not allow to write the file on `:w!`. It prints error "E504".

Comment: Ahhh you're right.. Thanks! I can accept that as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just told Vim that it should run in "readonly mode". The file itself is not readonly. If you `chmod -w foo`, then Vim would not allow to write the file on `:w!` while `W` is present in cpoptions.

You could try to start Vim with `-M`:

```
vim -M foo
```

This disallows any changes to the file and prevents writing the file. See `:help -M`.

Another solution might be:

```
vim -m foo
```

This opens the file and you can edit it (you get the warning `W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file`), but you are not able to write it. The option `write` is reset (to `nowrite`) and prevents writing to any file. So this is global.

If you finally decide, that you need to write it anyway, you have to set the option with the command `:set write`. As said, this is global, so you are than able to write any file.

Comment: Actually, I want to be able to change the contents of the files, just not save them. But then I also noticed now that there is a -m option, that prevents all kinds of saving.. HOWEVER.. I also would like to run :TOhtml and save the diff as html and -m prevents saving the html :-D

Comment: Perfect. -w in combination with set [no]write solved my problems! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to work on the file permissions, or to use the `-M` option as stated by @user7369280, but the funny thing is you can also launch `vi` with certain options that will prevent you to use the classic `w` or `wq` commands for example:

```
vi my_file -c 'cabbrev w <esc>' -c 'cabbrev wq <esc>'
```

It basically disables the commands `w` and `wq` with redefining them with the command `escape` (which doesn't do much)

Comment: You can still break out of that, though, with careful character entry and deletion, and cursor movements. Also, there are more commands that write files: `:wa`, `:x`, ...

Comment: For some reason, those cabbrev commands/options does not seem to work for me, I can still save with :w / :wq

Comment: @boffman it might depends on the vi version. It's actually a vim only feature. You may try with `ab` instead of `cabbrev`. For example: `vi my_file -c 'ab wq <esc>'`